# Traffic control Linux

Tags: tc, linux

Разъясните в краце как устроен TC. Допустим есть канал

```
tc class` add dev ${IFACE} parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100Mbit burst 2k
```

создаю класс например

```
`tc class add dev ${IFACE} parent 1:1 classid 1:70 htb rate 1028kbit burst 2k   tc qdisc add dev ${IFACE} parent 1:70 handle 70: sfq perturb 1 `
```

естественно фильтр

```
tc filter add dev ${IFACE} parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 handle 70 fw flowid 1:70
```

на фаерволе маркирую пакеты скажем для 5ти человек маркером 70! Внимание вопрос: Каждый из 5ти человек будут иметь канал в 1028kbit/s или будит на всех 1028.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на всех 1028

Comment: ок я уже разобралсо